# How to make new line in span text?

Tags: php, html, line, addition

I have this little code (php):

```
echo "<span class='hint--bottom' data-hint='$nickname <br /> swag'><img src='https://cravatar.eu/helmavatar/$nickname'width='29px' height='29px' /></span> ";
```

When i try to run it on website, this is what I get:

```
Polowicer <br /> swag. - Its a text.
```

How to add (if its possible) `<br />` to that data-hint?

I tried `\n, \r\n` and none worked.

Comment: what's your desired result ?

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam I wish to get something like this:
Polowicer *line break*
swag

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam Well, i dont know how to show you this in comment section, so i made a paint graphic :)
http://snag.gy/MDfvI.jpg

Comment: You can try with `%lt;br /&gt;` but without the JS part that is responsible for showing the actual hint I don't think we will be able to help you.

Comment: use nl2br(); to break line

Comment: @awons this isnt working, it only shows: Polowicer %lt;br /> swag, without new line.

Comment: @saty I should use it by "echo nl2br("my code");" ?

Comment: Sorry, it shoud be `&lt;br /&gt;`

Comment: @MaksymilianBukała   yes absolutely!!

Comment: you want to add new line inside this `data-hint='$nickname <br /> swag'` for attribut `data-hint` ? really ?

Comment: @DarkBee Yes, thats true.

Comment: @awons It only shows <br />, no new line.

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam Yes, im using hint.css and i want to add new line there.

Comment: @MaksymilianBukała, check Darkbee answer... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [hint.css](http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/) you'll need to alter some CSS to make it work and then you can create the breaks with the character `&#10;`

```css
  .hint:before, .hint:after, [data-hint]:before, [data-hint]:after {
 white-space : pre!important;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/hint.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <p>
 <a href="#" class="hint--top" data-hint="Yeah,&#10; I am >:D">Look, there is something over me.</a>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```